# How do I store this data in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, data-structures

I want a dictionary of values.  The keys are all strings.  Each key corresponds with some sort of list of strings.  How do I make a list of strings for each key and update that accordingly? I'll explain:

I have a loop that is reading lines of a word list.  The words are then converted into a string code and set as keys in the dictionary.  Here is an example of the string code/word relationship.

123, [the]

456, [dog]

328, [bug]
...

However, my program keeps looping through the word list and eventually will run into a word with the same code as "the", but maybe a different word, lets say "cat". So I want the list to look like:

123, [the, cat]

456, [dog]
...

How do I get it to make an arraylist for every key that I can then add to on the fly when needed?  My end goal is to be able to print out the list of words in that list for a called code (.get())

Comment: Can you provide some of your existing code?

Answer (score 3):

You can make a `HashMap`. In your case 
`HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>` works fine.

Comment: I know that, but if I do List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
then won't my data go away once I go back through my loop?

Comment: Can you give me a fuller picture of your code? I don't see this being a problem, but it's hard to tell without a larger snippet.

Comment: I am going to experiment with this now.  I am still in the planning phase of this project :/  Thanks.  I'll get back to you soon hopefully haha!

Answer (score 2):

Like it has already been said, a MultiMap seems to be what you need. [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap) that was already suggested and it's a good option. There is also and implementation from [commons-collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiValuedMap.html) you can use.

From commons-collections documentation:

```
 MultiValuedMap<K, String> map = new MultiValuedHashMap<K, String>();
 map.put(key, "A");
 map.put(key, "B");
 map.put(key, "C");
 Collection<String> coll = map.get(key); // returns ["A", "B", "C"]
```

You can always implement your own MultiMap if you don't want to use an external library. Use a `HashMap<String,List<String>>` to store your values and wrap it with your own put, get and whatever other methods you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a `Multimap` from [the Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained).

You can also go the route of using a `Map<Integer, List<String>>`, but then you will need to manually handle the case where the list is null (probably just allocate a new list in that case).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a HashMap that links each id to a list of strings:

```
Map<String, List<String>> dictionary = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
```

Now let's say you read two Strings: `id` and `word` . To add them to your dictionary, you can first verify if your id has already been read (using the `containsKey()` method)- in which case you just append the word to the list corresponding to that id - or, if this is not the case, you create a new list with this word:

```
//If the list already exists...
if(dictionary.containsKey(id)) {
    List<String> appended = dictionary.get(id);
    appended.add(word); //We add a new word to our current list
    dictionary.remove(id); //We update the map by first removing the old list
    dictionary.put(id, appended); //and then appending the new one
} else {
//Otherwise we create a new list for that id
    List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
    newList.add(word);
    dictionary.put(id, newList); 
}
```

Then whenever you want to retrieve your list of strings for a certain id you can simply use dictionary.get(id);

You can find more information on HashMaps on the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Comment: Thanks.  I'll mess around this now.

Comment: Update: I am getting an error where it cannot find the .add method for the dictionary..?

Comment: I understand this now and is exactly what I want, but it is still not compiling. Unknown symbol .add for the dictionary and I even have java.util.* imported.  I am compiling this via terminal.

Comment: FINAL UPDATE: FIXED IT.  I changed the code to what I KNEW had to work haha.     dictionary.add(appended); should have been dictionary.put(id, appended) and similarly for the "else" statement should be .put.  Thanks though.  Exactly what i wanted :)))

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you didn't want repeats in your list so I used Set instead.

```
Map<String,Set<String>> mapToSet = new HashMap<>();
List<String []>keyvals = Arrays.asList(new String[][]{{"123","the"},{"123","cat"}});
for(String kv[] : keyvals) {
    Set<String> s = mapToSet.get(kv[0]);
    if(null == s) {
        s = new HashSet<String>();
    }
    s.add(kv[1]);
    mapToSet.put(kv[0], s);
}
```

Comment: This is not dynamic.  I need to use arraylists because It is being made in a large loop.

Comment: Just replace the array with an array list.